# Why $\inf _{k \geq n} f_k $ is a nondecreasing sequence?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Why $g_n =\inf _{k \geq n} f_k $ is a nondecreasing sequence? Given that $f_k$ are non negative for all $k$?

I believe it is because if $m > n$, then $\{f_n\} \subseteq \{ f_m \} $ and hence $\inf_{k \geq m} f_k > \inf_{k \geq n} f_k $. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct, but it is possible that $\inf_{k \geq m} f_k = \inf_{k \geq n} f_k$. The infimum of the smaller set must be greater or equal to the infimum of the greater one.

Answer (score 0):

When you take the infimum over a smaller set, the infimum gets larger.